# Tracking numbers aren't submitting to fulfillment in orders on Shopify

Tags: shopify

Working on the fulfillment cycle on some middleware and after beginning to automatically fulfill orders, I noticed that none of the orders have their perspective tracking numbers associated with the fulfillment. 
I have the following PHP code submitting the fulfillment request:

```
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://'.$this->config->item('api_key').':'.$this->config->item('api_pass').'@'.$this->config->item('api_domain').'/admin/orders/'.$order['order_id'].'/fulfillments.json',
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'HAC',
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT =>30,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fulfill_json
            );
        if($send == true){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            $response_header = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);
            if($response_header == 201){
                //success

            }else{
                //error

            }
        }
```

Here's an example of the $fulfill_json I'm sending:

```
{"fulfilment":{"tracking_number":"1Z6V66666666666666","notify_customer":true,"line_items":[{"id":111111111}]}}

{"fulfilment":{"tracking_number":"1Z6V66666666666666","notify_customer":true,"line_items":[{"id":111111111},{"id":111111111},{"id":111111111}]}}
```

To me it looks like correctly submitted JSON, not sure if there's anything else wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd try changing is your spelling:

**fulfillment**   not     **fulfilment**

Comment: Good catch! That was probably it.